# How can I store primary keys within an url path in slickgrid rows?

Tags: slickgrid

I have been trying to follow examples but no success.

Comment: Can you give an example? It's not exactly clear from the question what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You're question might be a bit too specific to answer. You might want to try the slickgrid wiki. Good luck, Jeff.

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki